# How to remove Save Information to Pay faster next time option in Stripe Checkout

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm implementing a stripe checkout page using [Integration Builder](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder).

Build in integration have Save information features and I want to remove it.

I'm looking up the elements and I didn't find to remove this option. Anybody have experience that?

[image]

Here is my checkout session;

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'sgd',
          product_data: {
            name: clientDetail.name,
          },
          unit_amount: clientDetail.inclusive_price * 100,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.DOMAIN}/successful`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.DOMAIN}/subscribe`,
  });
```

Comment: It's the setting on https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout for 'Link with Stripe'.

Comment: now its called enable link : Customers can save their payment information to pay with 1 click on your site and other sites using Link. Learn more

Answer (score 0):

From Stripe Support:

Hi there,

Thank you for reaching out. I understand that you want to remove the option in saving your customer’s card information. Let me help you with this.

In order for you to disable the checkbox "Securely save my information for 1-click checkout" you need to turn off link with checkout in your link setting on your Stripe dashboard here:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/link

You can also refer to this document here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/link/checkout-link#accept-a-payment

I trust I was able to answer your queries. If you need anything else, please feel free to reach out anytime.

Comment: Roger, is there a way to do this within the Stripe React-Native SDK? I need it enabled/disabled under certain conditions.  Setting this in the dashboard won't work as we want it enabled for our users, but need it disabled for our cashiers.

Comment: You can maybe create two products... Use one for your customers other to  your cashier. You can add me on linkedin to any further questions https://www.linkedin.com/in/roger-gusmao-1a74ba29/